# How can i match the author with user profile in json?

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to match the author of the article with the user but i don't know how.

Here is **Models**

```
class Post {
  final String id;
  final User user;
  final String author;
  final String caption;

  Post({this.id,this.author, this.caption});

  factory Post.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return Post(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      caption: jsonMap['caption'] as String,
      author: jsonMap['author'] as String,
    );}}
----
class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String username;

 User({this.id,this.email, this.username,});


  factory User.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    return User(
      id: jsonMap['id'] as String,
      email: jsonMap['email'] as String,
      username: jsonMap['username'] as String,
    );
  }}
```

I also have functions to get the users and articles from Json as fetchPosts() and fetchUsers()
Now here is the json part of info

```
//Post
[
    {
        "id": "dfb2ce96-acab-44ab-8fbc-88f1bbd1b75b",
        "author": "dbb0446d-d0ec-4c24-9c1e-8ca9b6b06a7d",
        "caption": "caption here",
       
    }
]
---
//User

[
   {
        "id": "dbb0446d-d0ec-4c24-9c1e-8ca9b6b06a7d",
        "email": "user97972@gmail.com",
        "username": "user97972"
}
]
```

Now what i want to do is,if the "post.author" matches with any "user.id"(they are unique),i should be able to refer to user that is matched as "post.user".How can i do it?

**Update 1**: When i create a post it only shows the author with it's id. So i want to refer to full User instead of just an id.Something like this:

It only posts as string which comes as "Post.author", which only prints it's id.

What i exactly want is to refer it as user, which post.author matches with the identical user.id so it refers to post.user.

Answer (score 0):

You can create like below.

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Post {
    final String id;
    final User user;
    final String author;
    final String caption;
  Post({
    this.id,
    this.user,
    this.author,
    this.caption,
  });

  Post copyWith({
    String id,
    User user,
    String author,
    String caption,
  }) {
    return Post(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      user: user ?? this.user,
      author: author ?? this.author,
      caption: caption ?? this.caption,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'user': user?.toMap(),
      'author': author,
      'caption': caption,
    };
  }

  factory Post.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
  
    return Post(
      id: map['id'],
      user: User.fromMap(map['user']),
      author: map['author'],
      caption: map['caption'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Post.fromJson(String source) => Post.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Post(id: $id, user: $user, author: $author, caption: $caption)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;
  
    return o is Post &&
      o.id == id &&
      o.user == user &&
      o.author == author &&
      o.caption == caption;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
      user.hashCode ^
      author.hashCode ^
      caption.hashCode;
  }
}

class User {
  final String id;
  final String email;
  final String userName;
  User({
    this.id,
    this.email,
    this.userName,
  });

  User copyWith({
    String id,
    String email,
    String userName,
  }) {
    return User(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      userName: userName ?? this.userName,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'email': email,
      'userName': userName,
    };
  }

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
  
    return User(
      id: map['id'],
      email: map['email'],
      userName: map['userName'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory User.fromJson(String source) => User.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  @override
  String toString() => 'User(id: $id, email: $email, userName: $userName)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object o) {
    if (identical(this, o)) return true;
  
    return o is User &&
      o.id == id &&
      o.email == email &&
      o.userName == userName;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode ^ email.hashCode ^ userName.hashCode;
}
```

Comment: I will try it and respond if it worked or not as soon as possible.Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think == operator of Post class must check post id ONLY, imagine if the author will change post title....after that .contains() will not work as intended (the same about User class)

Comment: @someuser the data is Json based. So with any patch/update operation it will need a refresh function so there is no issue with that but thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @Rajesh i can't see it exactly but where does the function check if the id's are same? I can't see the function that is working on it

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: check the Update 1 please.I detailed my issue fully there. The method you did above does not still work,giving the post.user as null